# Как отменить отрицательные значения у количество попыток?

Tags: javascript

По заданию у пользователя должно быть только 10 попыток ввести какое-либо число от 0 до 1000, но после 10 идут -1, - 2 и так далее, то есть test == 0 не срабатывает. Как это исправить?

```
let test = 10;
let hiddenNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        
(function() {
      (window.start = function() {
        
        if (test == 0) {
                alert("Вы исчерпали все попытки. Начните играть заново");
                return;
            }

            
        while (userNumber = prompt("Введите любое число в диапазоне от 0 до 1000")) {
            
            let num = Number(userNumber);
                if (isNaN(num)) {
                    alert("Введи число! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num === null) {
                    alert("Игра закончена");
            }
                if (num > hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Меньше! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num < hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Больше! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num === hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Вы угадали!");
                    break;
            }
                --test;
        }
    });
})();

window.start();
```

@Sergey Tatarincev, при добавлении confirm с вопросом "Хотите сыграть еще один раз?" попытки снова уходят в отрицательные значения. Что сделать в таком случае?

```
let test = 10;
let hiddenNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      
(function() {
      (window.start = function() {   
        while (userNumber = prompt("Введите любое число в диапазоне от 0 до 1000. У вас 10 попыток")) {
            test--;

            if (test == 0) {
                alert("Вы исчерпали все попытки.");
                confirm("Хотите сыграть еще один раз?");
                if (true) {
                    window.start();
                }
            }
            
            let num = Number(userNumber);
                if (isNaN(num)) {
                    alert("Введи число! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num === null) {
                    alert("Игра закончена");
            }
                if (num > hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Меньше! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num < hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Больше! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num === hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Вы угадали!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
})();

window.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сравниваете test ВНЕ цикла

```
let test = 10;
let hiddenNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        
(function() {
      (window.start = function() {
       

            
        while (userNumber = prompt("Введите любое число в диапазоне от 0 до 1000")) {
        if (test == 0) {
                alert("Вы исчерпали все попытки. Начните играть заново");
                return;
            }
            
            let num = Number(userNumber);
                if (isNaN(num)) {
                    alert("Введи число! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num === null) {
                    alert("Игра закончена");
            }
                if (num > hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Меньше! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num < hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Больше! Осталось попыток: " + test);
            }
                if (num === hiddenNumber) {
                    alert("Вы угадали!");
                    break;
            }
                --test;
        }
    });
})();

window.start();
```

Comment: Тогда куда поставить test?

Comment: Я поставила test++ на следующую строку после while и всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вопрос снят. Решение:

```
let playAgain = confirm("Будете играть еще?");
                    if (playAgain) {
                        test = 10;
                        alert("Осталось попыток: " + test);
                        continue;
                    }
```